# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta' upon migrating

Tags: django, django-orm, django-migrations

I moved my Inventory model to its own app and reset all migrations and the database. `python manage.py makemigrations` has no issues, but I get an error upon migrating. Hope someone could point me to a direction since the traceback doesn't seem very helpful to me for resolving the issue.

*I remove some parts of the code and traceback due to stack overflow limitations

Django version 4.0.2

*traceback*

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, inventory, item, project_site, requisition, sessions, transfer, users
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  ...
  Applying item.0001_initial... OK
  Applying project_site.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bernard\pelicans\imrs-capstone\imrs\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Bernard\pelicans\imrs-capstone\imrs\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Bernard\pelicans\imrs-capstone\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 
425, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
...
  File "C:\Users\Bernard\pelicans\imrs-capstone\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\models.py", line 92, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "C:\Users\Bernard\pelicans\imrs-capstone\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 364, in create_model
    if field.remote_field.through._meta.auto_created:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

*project_site/migrations/0001_initial.py*

```
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('item', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Cart',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('cartItemCount', models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Site',
            fields=[
                ...
                ('inventory_items', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, related_name='inventory_items', through='inventory.Inventory', to='item.Item')),
                ('siteCart', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, related_name='siteCart', through='project_site.Cart', to='item.Item')),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

*project_site/models.py*

```
class Site(models.Model):
    siteCart = models.ManyToManyField(
        'item.Item',
        through='Cart',
        through_fields=('site', 'cartItem'),
        blank=True,
        related_name='siteCart')
    inventory_items = models.ManyToManyField(
        'item.Item',
        through='inventory.Inventory',
        through_fields=('site', 'item'),
        blank=True,
        related_name='inventory_items'
        )
```

*inventory/models.py*

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey('item.Item', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

*inventory/migrations/0001_initial.py*

```
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('item', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Inventory',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('siteItemCount', models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)),
                ('siteItemStatus', models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=[(0, 'Above Threshold'), (1, 'Moderate'), (2, 'Low'), (3, 'Critical'), (4, 'Empty')], default=1)),
                ('siteItemTurnover', models.CharField(choices=[('S', 'Slow'), ('N', 'Normal'), ('F', 'Fast')], default='F', max_length=1)),
                ('siteItemMinThreshold', models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)),
                ('item', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='item.item')),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: @solarissmoke 4.0.2 :)

Comment: The `Site.inventory_items` filed has `through='inventory.Inventory'` but the `inventory` app is not listed in your migration's dependencies. Try deleting the migration and recreating it. Can you share your models?

Comment: @IainShelvington Added my Inventory and Site models. I've tried deleting and recreating all migrations, but I get the same error.

Comment: Do you have a migration file in the `inventory` app named `inventory/migrations/0001_initial.py`?

Comment: @IainShelvington Added the migration file for inventory.

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with circular migration dependencies, both `project_site` and `inventory` depend on each other. If you wish to keep your current app/model structure you need to break your migration files up so that they can be applied in steps where there are no circular dependencies.

First remove the `ManyToManyField` that references the model in `inventory` from the `Site` model migration

project_site/migrations/0001_initial.py:

```
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('item', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        ...
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Site',
            fields=[
                ...
                # delete this line ('inventory_items', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, related_name='inventory_items', through='inventory.Inventory', to='item.Item')),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Then add the initial `project_site` migration as a dependency in the initial `inventory` migration

inventory/migrations/0001_initial.py:

```
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('item', '0001_initial'),
        ('project_site', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    ...
```

Then create a new migration in `project_site` that adds the `ManyToManyField`, this should now be possible because the through model has already been created

project_site/migrations/0002_add_m2m.py:

```
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('project_site', '0001_initial'),
        ('inventory', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='Site',
            name='inventory_items',
            field=models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, related_name='inventory_items', through='inventory.Inventory', to='item.Item')
        )
    ]
```